# SQL update query to replace column value from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

### There is a main table PD:
colA    colB    colC

### xxx     a       abc
yyy     b       def
zzz     c       adf
And the other one:
col1    col2

xxx     1
yyy     2
zzz     3

I want the values in colA of first table to be replaced with values in col2 from table2

Comment: You told us what you want (in as few words as possible), but you haven't asked a question. What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an update with a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE PD t1
SET colA = (SELECT t2.Col2 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Col1 = t1.colA);
```